# How do I use the Manifold plugin with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm attemting to use the Manifold plugin as follows:

```
@Test
    void printBoard() {
        @JailBreak TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
        game.printBoard();

        assertEquals("- ,- ,-\r\n- ,- ,-\r\n- ,- ,-", outputStreamCaptor.toString()
                .trim());
    }
```

I want to add some more assertions that test whether the board is printed correctly after I alter the private board variable in game (this is why I want to use the JailBreak annotation.

I've installed the plugin in Intellij by going to settings > plugins > searching for manifold > installing/applying it. I then restarted my IDE and no luck (compiler doesn't recognize @JailBreak).

Does anyone have any ideas about what could be going wrong? I'm using Java8 if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Manifold plugin analyzes your project's build configuration to dynamically apply features, such as support for type-safe reflection via @Jailbreak.  See the [manifold-ext setup instructions](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-ext#using-this-project). In Gradle terms, to support @Jailbreak your project must have an *implementation* dependency on `manifold-ext-rt` and an *annotationProcessor* dependency on `manifold-ext`. Additionally, you need to add the `-Xplugin:Manifold` compiler argument.  This info is detailed in the [setup docs](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/tree/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-ext#using-this-project).

If you are not using Gradle or Maven, you can configure your IntelliJ project directly using [Manifold binaries](http://manifold.systems/docs.html#download) in your module's dependencies settings. You also need to directly set compiler arguments (`-Xplugin:Manifold` and `-processorpath`) via File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler.

Comment: if anyone use extension method class, package name of class need starts with `extensions`, suffix with targe class full name, e.g. `java.io.File`, result is `extensions.java.io.File`